# Saying .match() isn't a function in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use a regex to find links in a string, but when I use t.match() on *link*, It gives an error saying it isn't a function.

```
var link = location.href;
var regex = /[^\?]*$/gi
var foo = link.match(regex);


var islink = foo.match(/^(http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?|ftp:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(\/(.)*)?(\?(.)*)?/gi);
alert(islink);
```

Could someone tell me what is happening?

Comment: The variable `foo` is an array of strings, you should try `foo[0].match...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` creates array.use `foo[0]`

```js
var link = location.href;
var regex = /[^\?]*$/gi
var foo = link.match(regex);

var islink = foo[0].match(/^(http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?|ftp:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(\/(.)*)?(\?(.)*)?/gi);
console.log(islink);
```